# My angularfire and angularJS is not working

Tags: html, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

Even though I have copied the whole code from angularfire main repository but the code just doesn't work.

I have gone through the code many times. The error says that angular is not defined even though all my files are connected and angular must be working.

I have this structure

- [index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/geFx3.png)
- [app.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPrqT.png)

This is the error

> uncaught reference error: angular is not defined app.js:19
>   uncaught error: [$injector:modulerr]. angular.js:38

Comment: Angular is not loaded in your app. Please load angular before your app.js file.

Comment: @varit05 see index.html

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 2):

@Moeid the best way to get started with Angular 1.5 and Firebase is following the documentation provided at the Github repository https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/quickstart.md

Try again following this step by step and let us know if you find any error.

Answer (score 0):

By Looking at your index file. Load `app.js` at the end of all third party `js`. So sequence would be

- angular.js
- firebase.js
- angularfire.min.js
- app.js

It will work.